# Python: Sampling indices from a list with constraints

Tags: python, algorithm

I want to know how to sample indices from a list with some constraints like below:

```
               1111
     01234567890123
a = "ABAAABABBBABAB"
b = "ABABBB"
```

The problem is how to find the ordered sampled characters of `a` that are equal to `b`

so, the answer of problem should be like below,

```
[0, 1, 2, 5, 7, 8],
[0, 1, 2, 5, 7, 9],
[0, 1, 2, 5, 7, 11],
...,
[2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
...
```

Because `b` is equal to `a[0] + a[1] + a[2] + a[5] + a[7] + a[8]`.
So `[0, 1, 2, 5, 7, 8]` is one answer of the problem.
But the indices of answer should be satisfied with ordered conditions.
It can not be `[2, 1, 3, 5, 7, 8]`.
`a[2] + a[1] + a[3] + a[5] + a[7] + a[8]`  is equal to `b`, but it can not be satisfied with the ordered state condition.

the length of `a` is 22 and the length of `b` is always smaller than length of `a`.

I implemented brute force to solve this one, but It takes large time complexity.

Is there better algorithm than brute force?
If there is, how should I implement it?

Comment: Please show the code you've already written. There may be a simple mistake in there

Comment: Is it okay to produce just one list, such as `[0, 1, 2, 5, 7, 8]`, or do you need an algorithm to produce all possible lists of indices to build b from a?

Comment: @Stef I need all possible lists of indices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly this is a [global sequence alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_alignment#Global_and_local_alignments) problem, which you can solve using [BioPython](https://biopython.org/docs/1.75/api/index.html):

```
from Bio import pairwise2

a = "ABAAABABBBABAB"
b = "ABABBB"

for alignment in pairwise2.align.globalxx(a, b):
    positions = [i for i, v in enumerate(alignment.seqB) if v != "-"]
    print(positions)
```

**Output** *(partial)*

```
[0, 1, 6, 7, 8, 13]
[0, 1, 4, 7, 8, 13]
[0, 1, 3, 7, 8, 13]
[0, 1, 2, 7, 8, 13]
[0, 1, 4, 5, 8, 13]
[0, 1, 3, 5, 8, 13]
[0, 1, 2, 5, 8, 13]
[0, 1, 4, 5, 7, 13]
[0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 13]
[0, 1, 2, 5, 7, 13]
```

Comment: I tried it and it looks like the number of alignments produced by `pairwise2.align.globalxx(a, b)` is capped at 256?

Comment: @Stef I think is capped at 1000.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution would be:

```
a = "ABAAABABBBABAB"
b = "ABABBB"

total_res = []
def find_indices(index):
    b_index = 0
    res = []
    for c in range(index, len(a)):
        if b_index > len(b) - 1:
            break
        if a[c] == b[b_index]:
            res.append(c)
            b_index += 1
    if res not in total_res and res:
        print(res)
        total_res.append(res)
for c in range(len(a)):
    find_indices(c)
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 5, 7, 8]
[2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[6, 7, 10, 11, 13]
[10, 11, 12, 13]
[12, 13]
```

Comment: Why bother with `a_lst, b_lst = list(a), list(b)`? Strings are already iterable and can be indexed and lengthed, this seems like it doesn't serve a purpose

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy correct, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot be done in constant time, but can be done with roughly linear time complexity (at least, with respect to `A` - I think the upper bound of complexity of this is `O(A * B)`) as follows:

```
def indices(A, B):
    # store partial patterns and complete patterns as we go
    # partial patterns will be stored in a list, where each element
    # is a 2-tuple (next_char_of_B_to_look_for, current_index_list)
    partial_patterns = []
    complete_patterns = []
    for (idx, char) in enumerate(A):
        # look for the next element, for any partial patterns we have
        # if we find it, then mark the index and increment the char to look for
        for p in partial_patterns:
            if p[0] < len(B) and char == B[p[0]]:
                p[1].append(idx)
                p[0] += 1
                # p[0] == len(B) indicates a completed pattern, and also 
                # will stop this `if` from being triggered again for this 
                # now-completed pattern (which will be ignored hereafter)
                if p[0] == len(B):
                    complete_patterns.append(p[1])
        # always look for the first element of B to start a new partial pattern
        if char == B[0]:
            partial_patterns.append([1, [idx]])
    return complete_patterns

a = "ABAAABABBBABAB"
b = "ABABBB"
indices(a, b)
# [[0, 1, 2, 5, 7, 8], 
#  [2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 
#  [3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 
#  [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

I believe this is the correct output for the given input (as index 6 is the last `A` with at least three `B`s following it)

Comment: I'm pretty convinced a greedy algorithm would be O(A+B) = O(A), by advancing on both strings simultaneously. If you end up with a complexity proportional to A*B then you must be doing something unusual.

Comment: @Stef I say `A * B` because of accounting for multiple lists of indices

Comment: Ooooooh, you want to produce **all** possible lists of indices? I think the OP was only asking to produce one list.

Comment: But in that case the complexity can be much much worse than simple A*B; imagine for instance that for some integers k and n, we set `b = "ab" * k = "abab...ab"` and `a = ("a"*n+"b"*n)*k = "aaaabbbbaaaabbbb...aaaabbbb"`. Then `len(b) == 2*k` and `len(a) = 2*n*k`, but the number of possible solutions is more than `n**k`. If for instance n is fixed and k goes to infinity, then the complexity is exponential in len(a), which is much much much worse than O(`len(a)*len(b)`).

Answer (score 0):

Build a table similar to that of [Longest common subsequence problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem), then extract all LCS's using section [Reading out all LCSs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem#Reading_out_all_LCSs) (here LCS is B sequence)