# Counting the number of ways to make up a string

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have just started learning dynamic programming and was able to do some of the basic problems, such as fibbonaci, the knapsack and a few more problems. Coming across the problem
below, I got stuck and do not know how to proceed forward. What confuses me is what would be the base case in this case, and the overlapping problems. Not knowing
this prevents me from developing a relation. They are not as apparent in this example as they were in the previous ones I have solved thus far.

> Suppose we are given some string origString, a string toMatch and some number maxNum greater than or equal to 0. How can we count in how many ways it is possible to take maxNum number of nonempty and nonoverlapping substrings of the string origString to make up the string toMatch?
>
> **Example:**
>
> If origString = "ppkpke", and toMatch = "ppke"
>
> maxNum = 1: countWays("ppkpke", "ppke", 1) will give 0 because toMatch is not a substring of origString.
>
> maxNum = 2: countWays("ppkpke", "ppke", 2) will give 4 because 4 different combinations of 2 substring made up of "ppkpke" can make "ppke".
> Those strings are "ppk" & "e", "pp" & "ke" , "p" & "pke" (excluding "p") and "p" & "pke" (excluding "k")

Comment: This is very similar to [Sampling indices from a list with constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69521813/python-sampling-indices-from-a-list-with-constraints), except you're only asking for the count rather than the list of results.

Comment: For instance if you want the total number of ways without choosing a specific value for k, then `from Bio import pairwise2; print(len(pairwise2.align.globalxx('ppkpke', 'ppke')))` will print 4.

Comment: Please clarify the expected output for `countWays("ppke", "ppke", 2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an initial word of caution, I’d say that although my solution happens to match the expected output for the tiny test set, it is **very likely wrong**. It’s up to you to double-check it on other examples you may have etc.

The algorithm walks the longer string and tries to spread the shorter string over it. The incremental state of the algorithm consists of tuples of 3 elements:

0. long string coordinate `i` (`origString[i] == toMatch[j]`)
1. short string coordinate `j` (`origString[i] == toMatch[j]`)
2. number of ways we made it into that^^^ state

Then we just walk along the strings over and over again, using stored, previously discovered state, and sum up the total number(s) of ways each state was achieved — in the typical dynamic programming fashion.

For a state to count as a solution, `j` must be at the end of the short string **and** the number of iterations of the dynamic algorithm must be equivalent to the number of substrings we wanted at that point (because each iteration added one substring).

It is not entirely clear to me from the assignment whether `maxNum` actually means something like “`exactNum`”, i.e. exactly that many substrings, or whether we should sum across all lower or equal numbers of substrings. So the function returns a dictionary like `{` #substrings `:` #decompositions `}`, so that the output can be adjusted as needed.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

def countWays(origString, toMatch, maxNum):
  origLen = len(origString)
  matchLen = len(toMatch)
  state = {}
  for i in range(origLen):
    for j in range(matchLen):
      o = i + j
      if origString[o] != toMatch[j]:
        break
      state[(o, j)] = 1
  sums = {}
  for n in range(1, maxNum):
    if not state:
      break
    nextState = {}
    for istart, jstart in state:
      prev = state[(istart, jstart)]
      for i in range(istart + 1, origLen):
        for j in range(jstart + 1, matchLen):
          o = i + j - jstart - 1
          if origString[o] != toMatch[j]:
            break
          nextState[(o, j)] = prev + nextState.get((o, j), 0)
    sums[n] = sum(state[(i, j)] for i, j in state if j == matchLen - 1)
    state = nextState
  sums[maxNum] = sum(state[(i, j)] for i, j in state if j == matchLen - 1)
  return sums

result = countWays(origString='ppkpke', toMatch='ppke', maxNum=5)

print('for an exact number of substrings:', result)
print(' for up to a number of substrings:', {
  n: s for n, s in ((m, sum(result[k] for k in range(1, m + 1)))
                    for m in range(1, 1 + max(result.keys())))})
```

This^^^ code is a quick and ugly hack and nothing more. There is a huge room for improvement, including (but not limited to) the use of generator functions (`yield`), the use of `@memoize` etc. Here’s some output:

```
for an exact number of substrings: {1: 0, 2: 4, 3: 8, 4: 4, 5: 0}
 for up to a number of substrings: {1: 0, 2: 4, 3: 12, 4: 16, 5: 16}
```

It would be an interesting (and nicely challenging) exercise to store a bit more of the dynamic state (e.g. to keep it for each `n`) and then reconstruct and pretty-print (efficiently) the exact string (de)compositions that were counted.

Comment: For comparison, my solution returns `[0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4]` when I run `[countWays('ppkpke', 'ppke', k) for k in range(6)]`

Comment: @Stef That sounds wrong, at least for 3 substrings, because either [it is possible to find 8 decompositions there](https://pastebin.com/gXKb4CkQ) or I misunderstood the task.

Comment: Fair enough; my solution doesn't allow adjacent substrings, so it doesn't count `(p   p) (k)         (e)`; but allows for "k or fewer" substrings rather than "exactly k" substrings.

Comment: I fixed my code so that it only allows for "exactly k" substrings. Now it returns [0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0]

Comment: To get that^^^ behavior (== to disallow adjacent substrings), my code can be adjusted like `range(istart + 1, origLen)`  `range(istart + 2, origLen)` and, further down, `result[k]`  `result.get(k, 0)`. However, IIUC, the task does **not** prohibit adjacent substrings. It says non-empty and non-overlapping, but adjacent should be accepted. Again, I may have misunderstood the task.

Comment: The OP has commented. Your interpretation was correct. I edited my code, now I also get [0, 0, 4, 8, 4, 0]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recursive solution.

Compares the first character of `source` and `target`, and if they're equal, choose to either take it (advancing by 1 char in both strings) or not take it (advancing by 1 char in `source` but not in `target`). The value of `k` is decremented everytime a new substring is created; there is an additional variable `continued` which is True if we're in the middle of building a substring, and False otherwise.

```py
def countWays(source, target, k, continued=False):
  if len(target) == 0:
    return (k == 0)
  elif (k == 0 and not continued) or len(source) == 0:
    return 0
  elif source[0] == target[0]:
    if continued:
      return countWays(source[1:], target[1:], k, True) + countWays(source[1:], target[1:], k-1, True) + countWays(source[1:], target, k, False)
    else:
      return countWays(source[1:], target[1:], k-1, True) + countWays(source[1:], target, k, False)
  else:
    return countWays(source[1:], target, k, False)

print(countWays('ppkpke', 'ppke', 1))
# 0
print(countWays('ppkpke', 'ppke', 2))
# 4
print(countWays('ppkpke', 'ppke', 3))
# 8
print(countWays('ppkpke', 'ppke', 4))
# 4
print(countWays('ppkpke', 'ppke', 5))
# 0
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate this. The solution may include substrings as far I understand

Comment: @TabPo Okay, I edited to allow adjacent substrings, by adding one recursive call in case `continued` is True.